# XFCE: How to find out which app is showing the tray?

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, system-tray, i3-wm

I'm trying to run status bars (with trays) like i3status and polybar on XFCE. xfce4-panel is disabled (confirmed by checking htop on startup) but I don't see tray icons shown in any of the alternative status bars. If I run xfce4-panel manually they appear in the XFCE panel, but I want to show them in i3status or polybar.

Questions:

- What do I do to make XFCE use something other than xfce4-panel as the tray? Note that I've enabled tray in my i3 and polybar configs.
- How do I check what process XFCE is using to show the tray?

Thanks.

Comment: DO NOT DO what the previous comment recommends. It will forcefully delete files your OS needs.